# How to re-write URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to re-write:

```
news.php?q=Contact+form+with+attachment
```

to look like:

```
news/Contact+form+with+attachment
```

my link looks like this

```
<a href="news/'.urlencode($row['title']).'">
```

and appears like this

```
http://localhost/untitled/public_html/news/Contact+form+with+attachment
```

in my `news.php file`, I have this code at the top

```
<?php $id = urldecode($_GET['q'])
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i','',$id);
     $query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = :id" ?>;
```

then in my .htaccess I wrote this

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_%+-]+) news.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

But when I click on the link it doesn't work it shows an empty/blank page
please help thanks

Comment: Take a look at apache log file you will find out what cause the error or at least the error notice.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you might be getting a white blank page because of a missing `;` in your php at the end of this line `<?php $id = urldecode($_GET['q'])`

I don't know if that's your whole problem, but start by adding that like this:

```
<?php 
  $id = urldecode($_GET['q']);
  $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i','',$id);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = :id" ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first variable `$id` wasn't correctly closed. Maybe the page is returning an empty or blank space because it's a fatal error. Change your code for this:

```
<?php 
$id = urldecode($_GET['q']);
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-zA-Z]#i','',$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = :id";
?>
```

Sorry for my english.